# PHP: указать непосредственно в скрипте путь для error_log

Tags: php, отладка, логирование

Здравствуйте, нашел функцию

```
error_log("Error message\n", 3, "/path/php.log");
```

где *`$1`* - строка сообщения, *`$2`* - тип доставки сообщения(в файл) и *`$3`* - путь

А как указать путем путь текущего каталога и желательно заоверрайдить все правила php.ini и .htaccess чтобы не смотря на правила хостера файл лога был в той же папке что и файл скрипта. Собираюсь вставлять код в каждый интересующий скрипт. И смортреть проблемы по адресу прописки.

`error_log("Error message\n", 3, "./");` - этого будет достаточно или нужно что-то типа:

```
--force

cows_superpower

!important
```

?

Для меня PHP это неизученная область, мне там не хватает console.log heroku logs --tail для nodejs. Прошу не удивляться сильно вопросу.

Получаю ошибку

```
> Warning: error_log(./): failed to open stream: Is a directory in
> /home/user***/public_html/index.php on line 20
```

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. Иду искать логи.

Comment: >файл лога был в той же папке что и файл скрипта.> Это не круто. Для пхп важен правильный отлов ошибок, и он может ловить всё в том числе нотайсы - такое желательно складировать в одном файле в папке сайта tmp/  , например. И пока идёт разработка/отладка, держать открытым этот файл в редакторе с автоподгрузкой, notepad++ напр.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр нет, нет, нет я не php-шник и не стану им. У меня привычка записать console.log, и либо нода сообшает об ошибках в серверную консоль либо браузер в клиентскую. Все интерактивно и быстро. Чтобы увидеть переменные скрипта на момент ошибки выполнения в бпаузере мне придется научиться писать возвращаемые функции и научиться рендерить данные с возвращаемых функций в index.php. Вашим путем мне нужно будет читать и другие ошибки которые то тут то там возникают и искать в длинном логе свою. А так запустил и посмотрел, поменял, запустил, посмотрел. Удобней если не php-шник.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр скажите пожалуйста а как дописывать в лог на PHP.
На bash, это **echo "rewrite" > error.log** перезапись
а это **echo "write" >> error.log** запись в конец файла

Есть ли такие различные способы записи  в php?

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр что такое нотайсы?
Если б у меня был vps-сервер, где я сам себе барин, то поинтересовался бы правильными способами отлова ошибок, но так как это безплатный хостинг и востановить доступ к логированию после удаления фала логов, требует обрашения к хостеру и другие ограничения..., то я начал искать способ злостно и локально решить проблему способом "всегда сработает".

Comment: >а как дописывать в лог на PHP< он дописывает а не перезаписывает. >что такое нотайсы?< почитайте, развёрнуто про ошибки https://habrahabr.ru/post/161483/ >console.log< ну есть var_dump в php например, или var_export - это тоже самое что console.log для вас

Comment: >Если б у меня был vps-сервер,< - это тут причём. Как-бы удобнее разрабатывать и тестировать на локальном домене на локальном компе с OpenServer , а на хостинг заливать в одну команду. Ну и мне всё равно, кем вы там хотите стать - но ваши ругательства на язык, это его незнание . Хотите на нём писать - выучите прежде всего, как ловить ошибки и их исправлять - это база. Не хотите - тогда что задаёте тут вопросы?)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр на локальном все работает на сервере нет. VPS-сервер это линукс который я умею настраивать, бесплатный хостинг это ограничение на ограничении. Не работает конкретно один скрипт и интересуют переменные выполнения и окружения. У меня нету доступов к php.ini и к другим настройкам. Нужно просто вывести инфу со скрипта в файл это не обьязательно ошибки. Это будут строки, числа, масивы...